# sftp returns code 0 even if there is an error reported "Couldn't create directory: Failure"

Tags: bash, sftp

I am trying to write a Bash script responsible for creating a folder on a remote server.

Snippet:

```
!/bin/bash -e
echo "Creating remote folder."
echo mkdir test_folder | sftp -oPort=22 192.168.0.11:/tmp
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  echo "Transfer failed!"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Transfer complete."
fi
echo $?
```

The output is:

```
Connected to 192.168.0.11.
Changing to: /tmp
sftp> mkdir test_folder
Couldn't create directory: Failure
Transfer complete.
0
```

So there return code is 0 but obviously there was an error.

How can I catch the remote error and set an appropriate return code in the script?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use sftp's option `-b` (with a batchfile or bash's Process Substitution) and you'll get mkdir's return code.

```
sftp -b <(echo "mkdir test_folder") user@remotehost:/
echo $?
```

Output:

```
Changing to: /
sftp> mkdir test_folder
Couldn't create directory: Failure
1
```

or use this:

```
echo "mkdir test_folder" | sftp -b - user@remotehost:/
echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
```

---

From man sftp:

> `-b batchfile`: Batch mode reads a series of commands from an input batchfile instead of stdin.  Since it lacks user interaction it
>                should be used in conjunction with non-interactive authentication.  A batchfile of ‘-’ may be used to indicate standard input.  sftp will abort if any of the following commands fail: get, put, rename, ln, rm, mkdir, chdir, ls,
>                lchdir, chmod, chown, chgrp, lpwd, df, symlink, and lmkdir.  Termination on error can be suppressed on a command by
>                command basis by prefixing the command with a ‘-’ character (for example, -rm /tmp/blah*).

Comment: Thanks! Preferred the second option as it seems POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 0):

1) The usage of the $? variable is not correct. The problem is that you need to store the return value ($?) immediately after executing the sftp command. Otherwise you will get return value of another command. E.g.:

```
rm /directory_which/does_not_exists
echo $?
echo "Deleting directory ..."
```

is totaly different than:

```
rm /directory_which/does_not_exists
echo "Deleting directory ..."
echo $?
```

2) You can create remote directory by using ssh as well like

```
ssh username@192.168.0.11 "cd /tmp && mkdir test_folder"
```

Hope it helps...